# CollectionView Jerks/Stutters When Scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which shows a list of playlists and an image from one of the songs in the playlist.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {

    playlistCell*    cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[playlistCell alloc] init];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    MPMediaItem *rowItem = [[playlists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] representativeItem];

    UIImage *cellBG = [self getAlbumArtworkWithSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320) forPlaylist:[playlists objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    cell.image = cellBG;

    return cell;
}
```

However, it jerks/stutters when I scroll.  It's not smooth at all and can be a pain to scroll through.

How would I make this smoother?

Comment: do you load images from internet here?

Comment: Maybe `getAlbumArtworkWithSize:` is doing some heavy stuff, code ?

Comment: Nope, which is why I can't find any solution.  All solutions usually relate to pulling images from the internet

Comment: @Jkmn But surely once it's loaded the image, it shouldn't need to reload it from getAlbumArtworkWithSize again?

Comment: Well `getAlbumArtworkWithSize:` will be called many times, each time a cell that was offscreen appear on screen.

Comment: @Jkmn Ah dammit.  Is there any way to make it temporarily store it so it doesn't have to call the method each time?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the UI more responsive simply by loading your images in the background with GCD like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {

    playlistCell * cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[playlistCell alloc] init];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        MPMediaItem *rowItem = [[playlists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] representativeItem];
        UIImage *cellBG = [self getAlbumArtworkWithSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320) forPlaylist:[playlists objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.image = cellBG;
        });
    });
    return cell;
}
```